# Make executable a python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I discovered cx_freeze which allows to create some executable file for python file. So I have this easy code in python (hello.py) :

```
print "Hello"
```

and when I type in the terminal :

```
python setup.py build
```

where setup.py is like this :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


setup(

    name = "hello",

    version = "0.1",

    description = "this program say hello",

    executables = [Executable("hello.py")],

)
```

and then I have a folder build with an executable hello but when I try to execute I have this error message :

```
ImportError: No module named __startup__
```

Thank you for your help !